# Do you use 'twist someone's arm' to talk about relationship?

Tags: expressions

1. He didn’t want to **force himself** to keep the bad relationship.
2. He didn’t want to **twist his arm** to keep the bad relationship.

In [the dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twist%20someone%27s%20arm), *twist someone's arm* means to try to force someone to do something.

Is the second example sentence okay to mean 'force himself'? I'm curious if it's okay to use it to talk about relationship.

Comment: In sentence 1, to *force yourself* is compelling yourself to do something. However, to *twist an arm* is a form of torture when you are compelling someone else to do something. The sentence *He twisted his (own) arm* doesn't make much sense, so sentence 2 does not make sense.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *twist someone's arm* means, metaphorically, to use physical force to make them do something. You can't make yourself do anything by twisting your own arm, so the metaphor is not appropriate when speaking of forcing yourself to do something unpleasant.

Comment: Thank you so much!